# ReactJS routes, no carga funciona ProtectedRouted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He creado dos clases para proteger las rutas pero ninguna funciona

Comment: Pon el código _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask].